# Create options for custom checkbox field using Jira rest api

Tags: java, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create options for my custom checkbox field.
I need to do it dynamically for each issue. (Some of them can have different options). Is there a way to do it? If yes, what I do wrong?

```
{"update" : {},
"fields": {"summary": "Title",
"customfield_11357": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": "option",
    "custom": "com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:multicheckboxes",
    "customId": 11357,
    "set" : [
        {"name":"Name1"},
        {"name":"Name2"}
    ]
    
},
"issuetype": {"id": "10255"},
"parent": {"key": "DC-34511"},
"project": {"id": "11738"},
"reporter": {"id": "5dd3e833b63c210fr4b67g6e"}}}
```

Comment: Maybe you should tag your question [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) and **not** java?

Comment: @Abra, I send request from backed. It is written on Java.